# Priority on duplicated variable on host_var and group_var

Tags: variables, ansible

Ansible: 2.4.9

I have a duplicated var "office_suite", one in host_var file "office_suite: msoffice" and in group_var "office_suite: openoffice".

Which one of these are selected on install?

Thanks again.

Comment: This is covered within documentation. You will find the answer in [Understanding variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Thank's a lot @U880D for this link: [Understanding variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence)

"host_var" **override** a "group_var" as per the list in the link.

But this is false for my, ***my "group_vars" override*** "host_vars".

Cordially